# Laravel uploaded file not being read properly

Tags: php, laravel, file, laravel-5, upload

I am printing the contents of a simple file upload request in Laravel 5.6 and for some strange reason the file doesn't have any information attached to it.

```
public function uploadDocument(Request $request)
{
    $file = $request->file('file');
    dd($file);
}
```

It prints the following:

[image]

Which I found very strange as it has detected a file but doesn't have any file info. I have tried with multiple file types and get the same error.

I am using Laravel 5.6.23 and PHP version 7.1.9 on my local WAMP server

Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: What is missing here?

Comment: All of the file info: filename, pathname, size etc... they are all empty

Comment: I think you are missing the "error: 1" line.

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: There is an error uploading the file. E.g. The file size may be bigger than the php.ini upload_max_filesize configuration.

Comment: @HilmiErdemKEREN You were right, it was my `upload_max_filesize` that need to increased in php.ini